# Can I install a Windows Server 2012 virtual server using Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012 with the same exact product key?

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2012, licensing, hyper-v-server-2012

I've read everything I can find online, but I cannot find a simple answer to this question.

I have Windows Server 2012 Standard installed using a volume license product key.  The official product name is Windows Srv 2012 Standard MAK B in the Microsoft Volume Licensing Service Center.  Can I use Hyper-V on that server to create a new virtual server running Windows Server 2012 Standard and use the same exact volume license product key to activate it?  Simply put, can the physical server and the virtual server use the exact same product key?

My intuition says that it won't work for some reason, but I haven't found anything written in plain English that proves it won't.  I hope I'm wrong, and it would work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. It's a MAK, so you're supposed to use the same product key, up to the number of allowed activations. See [Microsoft's Volume Licensing FAQ](https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/existing-customers/product-activation-faq.aspx) for the full details.

Comment: So, it will work then!  I see that ratio of used/available MAK activations in the licensing center.  What puzzles me is that I have only performed 1 server installation using the license, but it says I have used 2 activations.  For that reason, I always thought something about it couldn't be trusted.

Comment: Did you blow it away and reinstall (and forget about it)?

Comment: We don't remember blowing it away and starting over for whatever reason, but who knows.  Either way, I have lots of activations left that can be used.

Comment: I down voted because this answer is incorrect. Windows Server 2012 Standard is licensed to run 2 virtual machines. This limitation has nothing to do with the number of activations left on the MAK key used by the server. A better link for information is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/briefs/virtual-licensing.aspx).

Comment: @MichaelSteele I don't think you understood the question.

Comment: @MichaelHampton There is no simple answer to his question, but using the same MAK key to activate both a host and a hyper-v guest is not the proper way to do it.

Comment: @MichaelSteele Huh, what? You're talking about a retail license, this is a Volume license with MAK (or KMS, if you fancy that). The correct way is to use the same key. No doubt about it. Nada. Trust me.

Comment: @pauska The document I linked to comes from Microsoft's volume licensing site, and is titled "Licensing Microsoft Server Products for Use in Virtual Environments".

Comment: As far as I can tell, @MichaelSteele you're confusing "have they purchased enough licences to make this all legal" with "how many times can a MAK key be re-used". The latter is what's been asked and answered here, the former is what you're talking about, or at least *closer* to what you're talking about.